# Matlab - How to use strings instead of numbers in bar figure

Tags: matlab, plot, label, bar-chart

I want to obtain a Matlab figure using the `bar` function but when the actual figure is plotted instead of displaying the numbers underneath each bar I want to display which represents that actual value plotted.

For example I am having the vector `x = [1 2 3]` and instead of showing 1, 2 and 3 beneath each plotted bar, I want to display a string corresponding to one of these values `y = {'sam'; 'alan'; 'ellie'}`

[image]

Could you please explain how could I obtain this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
x = [1 2 3];
str = {'sam'; 'alan'; 'ellie'};
bar(x)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str))
```

[image]

Comment: Using platinummonkey's solution including 'XTick', 1:4 (or 1:numel(Labels)) proved more robust for me than only using 'XTickLable' alone. Leaving out 'XTick'  caused the lables to be displaced in some cases.

Comment: @Jacob: sure, it wouldn't hurt to also specify `XTick`. I'm curious though, do you have an example where the labels are misplaced?

Comment: e.g.
            figure();
            hold on;
            bar([10 22 2 11]);
            Label={'#7','#8','#9','#10'};
            set(gca, 'XTickLabel', Label);
            hold off

Comment: It works if you do this: figure(); hold on; bar([10 22 2 11]); Label={'#7','#8','#9','#10'}; set(gca,'XTick',1:numel(Label), 'XTickLabel', Label); hold off

Comment: @Jacob: ah I see, good example. Execute your code one statement at-a-time, and you'll find out that `hold on` is the cause of the problem; it creates an axis with default tick marks, then when you add the bar plot to it, it apparently tries to maintain the same number of ticks. At this point the custom labels are applied in rotation (reused) since now you have more ticks than corresponding labels. I'm updating my answer, thanks Jacob.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/21178

```
Labels = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:4, 'XTickLabel', Labels);
```

if you need to change the Y-labels then substitute YTickLabel for XTickLabel