# Change the x-axis values to string values

Tags: matlab

I have a simple bar chart. Lets say it is plotting the sales value ($) for a list of different cities.

So my y-axis is the dollar value of sales. My x-axis is the list of cities. In matlab the cities in my x-axis are plotted as 1 to 25. How do I change the numbers from 1 to 25 to a string values, i.e. San Diego, New York, London etc? Also it would be useful to know how to rotate the string values 45 degrees as the string values might overlap each other making it hard to read.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: well all I have managed so far is the bar chart. I have seen how to change the x-axis to dates but not to strings

Comment: You couldn't have looked very hard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397234/matlab-how-to-use-strings-instead-of-numbers-in-bar-figure

Comment: As for the rotation, have you at least Googled it? This stuff is out there and not hard to find. Please at least indicate that you've tried in your question. These are not unsolved problems.

Comment: @Dan yes I have googled it. It's generally quicker to google most queries than it is to post a question and wait for an answer. I didn't know I needed to put in every post "I have googled help".

Comment: What you need to include is a reason why what you have tried hasn't worked. You've just asked for code. If you Google literally your exact title with "Matlab" at the end the first hit is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672637/how-to-use-string-as-data-for-plotting-in-matlab which answers your question exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [XTickLabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#XTickLabel).

For example,

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'San Diego';'New York';'London';'Chicago'})
```