# alter tick labels in bar plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Consider the following example:

```
aa = [911354,4049816,9041133,16045631,23974555,35821544,47721190,...
    63573808,84692546,106536581,134014666,168579941,200237804,...
    237840742,237840742];
aa2 = [0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7];

bar(aa2,aa/1e6,'histc');
xlim([0 7]);
```

which gives

[image]

How can I change this to have the x axis to show the range between the ticks e.g. 0.0 to 0.5, 0.5 to 1.0 and so on. Similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Have you at least read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543302/change-the-x-axis-values-to-string-values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xtick, like this:

`plot(x, y)
set(gca, 'XTick',0:0.5:7)`
That will give you numbers on either side of the bar, but if you want to show it as a range, look at the link Dan gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = cell(8/0.5,1);
for i = 0:0.5:7
   tmp{i*2+1} = sprintf('%d-%d',i,i+1);
end
set(gca,'XTickLabel',temp)
```

Read more about XTickLabel: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#XTickLabel

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers above solved the issue of using strings as ticks. However, this was not the entirety of the question. A large portion of the question was to rotate the test. The best solution I found was on the mathworks website. Using the [following](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate)http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate
 package to rotate the text.