# Matlab - How to use strings instead of numbers in bar figure with multiple bars per tick mark

Tags: matlab

First, I would like to point out that my question is an extension of [Matlab - How to use strings instead of numbers in bar figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397234/matlab-how-to-use-strings-instead-of-numbers-in-bar-figure). In the question mentioned above, it doesn't seem to mention what to do if there are multiple bars being used at each tick mark. I have attached my bar graph as a reference. [image: BarGraph]

Is there some way I can put strings corresponding to each tick mark on the x-axis for this plot, not each individual bar? Each group of bars should be labeled "Term A", "Term B", etc.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the solutions in the linked question? They work exactly the same even with grouped bars.

Comment: I did, they did not work the same.

Comment: This doesn't work for you?: `bar(rand(5,6)); set(gca,'XTickLabels',{'Term A'; 'Term B'; 'Term C'; 'Term D'; 'Term E'});`

Comment: I feel really stupid, I was using () instead {}. Sorry

Comment: Don't worry. Happens to all of us. :)